# Will the recently found OpenSSL vulnerability Heartbleed affect my public site for which I obtained an SSL certificate from a CA?

Tags: certificate-authority, openssl, heartbleed

I had generated the CSR with OpenSSL. Do I need to regenerate a new CSR with no vulnerability due to OpenSSL in order to obtain a new certificate from a CA?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you're using the same key, which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with CSR's generated with a vulnerable version of OpenSSL.

This doesn't mean your keys were not compromised via an actively running server, but it sounds like you understand that.